# Prevent or detect reading of daemon in memory

Tags: memory, daemon

Is it possible to prevent the memory being used by a daemon to be read by anything else?

If not, is it possible to detect an attempt to read?

If so, is it possible to get in front of the actual read and execute commands that can act first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Unixy systems, root is all-powerful and can certainly read (and even write) into your daemons' memory *without it even being able to find out*. Ditto for the user as which the daemon runs. If you are trying to protect against non-root/non-daemon-user access, the system itself should provide protection (modulo bugs or stupid configuration, that is).